# How can we unchange the value of a scoped variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to assign scoped variable to a normal javascript variable in AngularJS script, and modifying the value of normal variable.. But I see that based on the change that is made in normal variable, Scoped variable data gets changed automatically.. How can we unchange the data of Scoped Variable even after modifying the normal javascript variable?

Am using a button in HTML code to invoke the assign()

I have below AngularJS code

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ui.plot']);
app.controller('PlotCtrl', function ($scope) 
 {
    'use strict';
    $scope.sname = "Tttt";
    $scope.dataset_v = {
     "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 }, 
     "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
     "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
     "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
     "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
                       };

    $scope.assign = function () 
    {
        var dataset=$scope.dataset_v;
        // Declare resulting empty array
        var d = [];
        // Get object keys and iterate over them
          Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function (key)  
          {
            // Get the value from the object
            var value = dataset[key].value;
            // Update values if in the range
            if(value >= 10 && value <= 20) {
               dataset[key].value = 7;
            } else if(value > 20 && value <= 40) {
               dataset[key].value = 8;
            }
            // Push the updated(or not) value in the array
             d.push(dataset[key]);
     });
          alert(JSON.stringify(d, null, 4));
 });
</script>
```

After making the change on normal js variable i.e., dataset and d..

$scope.dataset_v should not get changed, so it should be original only like below, how can we do that ?

```
    $scope.dataset_v = {
     "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 }, 
     "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
     "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
     "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
     "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
```

}

Am using normal javascript variable (dataset and d) for storing modified values to post them to server for datastore (Internally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [**`angular.copy()`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). Instead of

```
var dataset = $scope.dataset_v;
```

use

```
var dataset = angular.copy($scope.dataset_v);
```

By that you preserve the original `dataset_v`.

Answer (score 2):

This :

```
var dataset=$scope.dataset_v;
```

Creates a new variable pinting towards the same array.

What you need is a new array. You should copy the entire array and modify the copy :

```
var dataset = angular.copy($scope.dataset_v);
```

`angular.copy` performs a *deep* copy, unlike direct assignement or `array.slice` wich creates a *shallow* copy (new array but same elements).